# Why does the system not automatically delete very bad answers?

Tags: feature-request

Why does not the system automatically delete very bad answers?

If an answer with less than -3 score and has more answers, why doesn't the system delete this answer automatic? 
(This can be done for inactive users over time.)

Comment: I change my question and add more idea.

Comment: Answers are downvoted for different reasons - including very wrong reasons to downvote, so a trigger on only a few downvotes like you propose can be quite damaging. Completely wrong answers have little value sure, but there are also answers which are a bad idea. The fact that it is a bad idea is still valuable information.